# How can I write an array's elements to a txt file, keeping the order of the elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have 2 arrays (same length) and I'd like to write content to a txt file, keeping the order of the elements. 
Something like this:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [a, b, c];
for (id in array1) {
      fs.appendFile(`./saved_items/output.txt`, 
      `${id}: ${array1[id] + numOfCredits[id]}\r\n`, 
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    }
```

So the output should be this:

```
0: 1a
1: 2b
2: 3c
```

But instead of this, I got the following output:

```
1: 2b
2: 3c
0: 1a
```

Why is that and how can I write to file and keep the order of the elements?

Comment: it's because `appendFile` is async, you could use the sync version, or use `Promise` to guarantee sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggesting an alternative:

Instead of executing `appendFile` in a loop, why not first build the data to write and then execute `appendFile` once:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [a, b, c];
let data = '';
array1.forEach((el, idx) => {
  data += `${el}: ${el + array2[idx]}\r\n`;
});
fs.appendFile(`./saved_items/output.txt`, data, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, after changing to appendFileSync, it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

As `appendFile` is an async function, your code can write data in other order then you call it, you should use chained calling of it or use sync version of `appendFileSync` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try forEach and dont use for..in to iterate and array. Also use `index` to retrieve the element from second array

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [a, b, c];
arr1.forEach(function(item, index) {
  fs.appendFile(`./saved_items/output.txt`,
    `${index}: ${item + array2[index]}\r\n`,
    function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
})
```